curl/curl.h header file undefined reference to 'curl_easy_...' error(C++)
I'm currently trying to use curl in c++.
I copied include folder in curl to my project folder, so include path seems nothing wrong.
But when I try to compile my codes to make .exe file,
undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
uundefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
uundefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
uundefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
uundefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'

this is the errors I got when tried to compile.
I found no fix about this error in internet.
Does anyone can help me about this issue?
(Using VSCode for editor)
I tried to make currency converter program in c++, so I needed curl to import API data.
But I encountered errors in curl.

You don't link with the cURL library. What does your configuration look like? Are you using the Microsoft C and C++ plugin, or the default code-runner plugin to build? I recommend you spend some time to read the Visual Studio Code documentation first.

If you simply copied the include folder, then you don’t have the sources for the declarations. You must link your program to the sources of the library you are using to have complete declarations and definitions else a linker error. Simply copying header files is not an installation.
As to why intellisense doesn’t warn you, it could be because it assumes that you have the sources properly linked to. Most intellisense programs and linters cannot detect that correctly. You should look into how to install curl and libcurl. [curl.se]
